# Custom encoder ignored by django JsonResponse

Tags: python, json, django, encoding, django-rest-framework

I am building an app using Django Rest Framework (Versions : django 3.1, djangorestframework 3.11.1, python 3.7)

I want to override the encoder used in JsonResponse.

An oversimplification of my problem:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class CustomEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o + 10

response = JsonResponse({"data": 1}, encoder=CustomEncoder)
```

What I expect from `response.getvalue()` is `'{"data": 11}'` but instead I get `'{"data": 1}'`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because DjangoJSONEncoder use for

```
JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to encode date/time, decimal types, and
UUIDs.
```

you must pass value like date/time, decimal types, or
UUIDs for your method override `default` be called.

Try change to

```
class CustomEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return int(o) + 10

response = JsonResponse({"data": Decimal(1)}, encoder=CustomEncoder)
```

it will return {"data": 11}